# converting XML to Pipe delimeted CSV

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am converting XML to Pipe delimeted CSV. So, in that the first column value i want to  split the string into 2 characters and the remaining should come below of the same row. But, here i am getting the remaining string in the next line 1st row.But i want to get in the same excel cell

I have using `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>`

Please find the screenshot below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl5Gg.png)

The above screenshot 13 value should come under 12.

Below is the sample XML:

```
<Family>
<Parent>
    <Boy>
        <name>Ram</name>
        <Age>05</Age>
    </Boy>
    <Girl>
        <name>Sita</name>
        <Age>06</Age>
    </Girl>
    <Girl>
        <name>Pooja</name>
        <Age>15</Age>
    </Girl>
</Parent>
<Parent>
    <Boy>
        <name>Ramesh</name>
        <Age>10</Age>
    </Boy>
    <Girl>
        <name>Geeta</name>
        <Age>26</Age>
    </Girl>
</Parent>
</Family>
```

Below is the XSLT used :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Family">
    <xsl:for-each select="Parent">
        <xsl:for-each select="Boy">
            <xsl:if test="name!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>|<xsl:for-each select="Girl">
            <xsl:if test="name!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>|<xsl:value-of select="'&#13;&#10;'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Observed output :

```
Ram|SitaPooja|
Ramesh|Geeta|
```

Expected Output :
Please refer the below screenshot for expected output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbmgM.png)

Explanation:
I want to have the name of the children for each parent in the CSV file. So if the parent has one boy and one girl we will have the name of the children in one row separated by pipe delimiter.

But the 1st Parent is having two girls so, I want Sita and Pooja should one below the other in the same cell of the CSV file. But currently we are receiving it one beside the other.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question and share the XML and XSLT.

Comment: Please check above xml and XSLT. Thanks

Comment: You would probably need to use one more delimiter to separate the values of children having same gender. So boys and girls will be separated by `|` and only boys or only girls will be separated by the new delimiter. When this file is imported in XLS, you will have to deal with both the delimiters to display the data according to the requirement.

Comment: Even if we use other delimiter for children of the same gender then also we dont get the names one below the other in the same excel cell. I want the values in the same cell means in the same way how we enter two values using alt+enter in the excel cell.

Comment: I don't think the CSV import to Excel would work directly for your requirement. You might have to do some programming in between when opening the CSV in Excel. XSLT will help in creating the CSV using multiple delimiters, however something like `Alt+Enter` is not possible within the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be on the 2nd column then you need to have some value for the 1st colunm.